# How to create and integrate Plugin for a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, add-in

I've been looking everywhere for an example or something like this, without any luck so i hope someone here can put me in the right direction.

I have a WPF application that i want to build plugins/DLC/add-in (not sure what the right word is to search on when it is WPF so i'll use Plugin).

I haven't build any plugins yet, because i thought there might be a smart `nuget package` or a `pattern` to use.

So essentially i want something that are not as tedious as (I know this is so simplified...):

```
if(myFolderPath contains "plugin.dll")
{
    AddAMenuButtonWithThePlugin();
}
```

I'm hoping for maybe some kind of `AnnotationMethod` like:

```
[UseThisDll("plugin.dll")]
private void AddAMenuButtonWithThePlugin(){...}
```

If you have had a similar task before i would like to hear how you solved this as i don't find my own ideas that easy for me to pull off.

Basically i have multiple PC's with the WPF that are using `Squirrel.Windows` for the install and update.

However i have some plugins that maybe only some of the PC's should have.

Any good advice? Basically i want to add a `button` to a `page` that will lead it to the DLC `page`.

Comment: Try using Mono.Addins (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Addins/), MEF(https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Composition) or (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Composition/)

Comment: Thanks @Tom i'll give them a look :)

Comment: You could pretty much be describing mef's capabilities with your requirement.

Comment: MEF is perfect for this. Never used it or got introduced to it before and i can see there is alot of examples on the net. Perfect! Tom or Andy would you create an answer so i can accept it? :)

Comment: I wrote an answer, if you still want to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MEF for this.

There are a few versions of MEF:

- System.ComponentModel.Composition. It's a part of .NET framework and also available as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Composition).
- System.Composition, which is a lightweight version. It doesn't allow for a dynamic recomposition, but it's faster than the first one. The Nuget package is also [available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Composition/).
- VS MEF which is implementation used by Visual Studio. It can reuse parts from the other two libraries. GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-mef).